# Trouble reading the text file format

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm having trouble reading the text file properly.  I believe I'm using the fscanf properly but not the formatting of the printf of the text file itself.

```
//student struc
struct student
{
    char header[50], name[20];
    int student_no;
    float subjectA,subjectB;
};


//Read data in file and store in struc
int readData(struct student stud[])
{
    char fname[70];
    printf("Please enter input file name:");
    scanf("%123s",fname); // scans the file name inputted
    strcat(fname, ".txt");
    printf("%s \n", fname);
   FILE *fp;//  pointer
   int i;
   fp=fopen(fname,"r" );//open file in read
   if(fp==NULL) //unable to open the file
   {
      exit(0);
   }
   i=0;
    
    
   //reads data and stores in student struc
   while(fscanf(fp,"%s%s%d%f%f",stud[i].header,stud[i].name,&stud[i].student_no,&stud[i].subjectA,&stud[i].subjectB)!=EOF)
   {
       i++;
   }
    
   fclose(fp);
   return i;
}


// print data function
void printData(struct student stud[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) // constantly populates the struc
    printf("\n \%-14s\%s\t\t%d\t\t%0.1f\t\t%0.1f",stud[i].header,stud[i].name,stud[i].student_no,stud[i].subjectA,stud[i].subjectB);

int main()
{
   struct student stud[100];
   int n;
    char opt = '\0';
    float sdA = 0.0,sdB = 0.0,avgA = 0.0,avgB = 0.0;
   n=readData(stud); //readData function
   printData(stud,n);//printData
    printf("\n");
```

This is the input file

```
STUDENT NAME    STUDENT NO  SUBJECT A   SUBJECT B
JOAN            1           70.5        85
TANIA           2           49          75
TOM             3           53          54
JEFF            4           80          49.5
SUSAN           5           20          20
KATHY           6           99          55
RAYMOND         7           22.5        75
```

This is the output I'm receiving.  It should represent the same format as the input text file.  Even when I take out the spaces, the program still reads the next line of the heade (top of the file) then creates a column.

```
STUDENT       NAME      1600735199      0.0     259660666015580160.0
 STUDENT       NO       32767       -230262611306872832.0       0.0
 SUBJECT       A        1644026974      0.0     0.0
 SUBJECT       B        32767       -226721427951190016.0       0.0
 JOAN          1        70      0.5     85.0
 TANIA         2        49      75.0        0.0
 TOM           3        53      54.0        4558848.0
 JEFF          4        80      49.5        0.0
 SUSAN         5        20      20.0        168040595456.0
 KATHY         6        99      55.0        0.0
 RAYMOND       7        22      0.5     75.0
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant information in the question body as properly formatted text, not as links to images.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question that I have ever posted.  How would I go about that? When I try to input a picture, it leads me to the tab to post as a link

Comment: Do *not* post pictures. Your question is about text files, with code which is text. There is no reason in the world not to post everything as text.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Find more helpful recommendations here [ask].

Comment: I believe I formatted the question properly.

Comment: The `char fname[70]; scanf("%123s",fname);` is trouble waiting to happen, if it hasn't already. Also can improve the test in `while(fscanf(fp, "%s%s%d%f%f", ... ) != EOF)` which should be `while(fscanf(fp, "%s%s%d%f%f", ... ) == 5)`. This covers EOF but also *incorrect data*.

Comment: True the question is formatted properly, but lacks the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which means a *complete* code that demonstrates the problem, which can be copy/pasted and compiled by readers *as-is*. That also means including all library headers, so that readers don't have to ask "did you include the library headers?"

Comment: ... the `fscanf` change shows up that you are reading 5 items when most lines in the file only have 4, so the data is getting out of alignment, as the output shows. The heading does have 5, and one way around the is to read every line with `fgets` and then to apply `sscanf` to the string.

Comment: @Yuffie Save time, drop all `fscanf()` calls and use `fgets, sscanf()`.

Comment: Your fscanf in the while would work properly only if the input had no spaces and columns.